# Calculate a quote price, and change the price of the product through JS. Is there a safer way?

Tags: javascript, forms, security, dynamic, price

So right now I am calculating a quote price based on user input which include: "Radio option 1, Radio option 2, duration and distance."

I am using JS to update a quote price based on what the user is selecting, and then it updates a field in a form, this field is used as the price that is sent to stripe.

How would I make this secure, do I have to scrap the JS because if the user goes into my Javascript with some searching they can find the calculation and alter it.

```html
function calcQuotePrice(state, deliv_dist, chauffeur_dist){
    var base_price = map[currentCarSelected]['basePrice'];

    var date1 = dateConverter(jQuery('#from').val(), jQuery('#fromTime').val());
    var date2 = dateConverter(jQuery('#to').val(), jQuery('#toTime').val());
    var duration = dateDiffInDays(date1,date2);
    var durationCost = dailyModifier(duration, base_price);
    var deliveryCost = calcDeliveryCost(deliv_dist);
    var totalCost = durationCost + deliveryCost;
    
    if(state === 'pick up'){
        totalCost = durationCost;
    }
    else if(state === 'delivered'){
        totalCost = durationCost + deliveryCost;
    }
    else{
        var chauffeurCost  = calcChauffeuerCost(chauffeur_dist, base_price);
        totalCost = deliveryCost + chauffeurCost;
    }
    
    jQuery('#quotePrice').find('p').html('Quote Price: £' + numberWithCommas(totalCost.toFixed(0)));
    jQuery('#price-field').val(totalCost);
}
```

My question is how would I do this in a secure way?

Comment: To make it secure you need to do this on the back end. It cannot be done securely in JavaScript

Comment: The answer is easy : you can't. It's impossible to secure client-side JS code, simply because it's necessarily public. All security must be handled by your server.

Comment: @ControlAltDel it can _perfectly_ be done securely in Javascript. On the server :)

Comment: @JeremyThille You are correct. I'm coming from being the father of a 3 and a 6 yr old, and mommy is always telling me "don't over-complicate the answer; you will only confuse them!" I apply that here as well :)

Comment: @JeremyThille sorry to bother you, but could you point me towards any resources that can help me learn how to do this? if you have any

Comment: Well, "How do I write a back-end" is pretty much as vast a question as "How do I build a rocket?" That's years of learning and studying and experience... Starting with "What language are you going to use for your back-end?" Python? Java? ~~~ NOT YOU, PHP ~~~ Javascript/Typescript? Ruby? That's a whole continent to explore here...

Comment: Just a simple Javascript backend script that runs when a button is clicked, i just need it to run a simple calculation function and change a value in an input field for a form.

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply to @JeremyThille, his comments here have confused you. He is talking about setting up a backend application server using node.js (Javascript-based). But serer side processing is completely separate from browser-side javascript processing, and the server side processing must complete before being sent to the browser (you can however use ajax in the browser to contact the server with another request on the same page). Sound confusing? It is. So stick with the answer that you can't do this securely in client-side Javascript

Comment: It's fine if it's confusing, I am open to learning even difficult things. So essentially what I can do if I understood that correctly is, run an AJAX callback similar to how google distance matrix works and get a response from my server if it matches with my client side JS calculation then it gives it the green light to go ahead and update the price field?

Comment: Nothing must be sent to Stripe from the front-end anyway, because everything can be manipulated, so nothing can be trusted. Your _server_ must do the transaction with the Stripe API.

Answer (score 0):

Any front-end code is inherently insecure and editable by the user.

To make things like this secure, a backend is often used to calculate cost and verify inputs before sending things to a payment engine like Stripe.

Alternatively if you want to keep things simple, you can just accept that risk of someone trying to pay you the wrong amount with Stripe, and then you just check the amount they paid you on Stripe before giving them the product.

What's the worst that can happen? Are you exposing your Stripe API key so they can give themselves refunds? or are you just letting them pay you an incorrect amount, which is their fault for giving you their money, and it becomes a legal issue as to what you are liable to give them in return.

Comment: It's for car rental so they wouldn't be getting any product until everything is confirmed, but i'd rather just make sure there's no way they can do something like that. I'l look into how to implement this into the backend now.

My stripe API key is safe, the worst that can happen is they mess with the quote prices and it slips through as the calculation is a little complex.

thank you for your reply